# Prevent NumExpr evaluation from breaking my bot (dpy)

Tags: python, discord.py, numexpr

I have a bot and I am trying to make a math command, I am using numexprs eval which works great but I have an issue. When a user uses the math command on an insanely high number (f. e. 8287467846 * 72846871642847846) the bot breaks, so I had to restrict the command. Is there a way I can make it public without people being able to break my bot? I am open to any libraries or whatever.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add validations to your bot

Comment: Havig a code example instead of plain text would be way more useful. If your bot just breaks because of the numbers being to high, add a `try - except` block.

Comment: It keeps trying to calculate and doesn't throw an error, that's why the bot crashes